# Jquery file with variable id as selector with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to change a micropost list element using an Ajax request. There are several microposts in that page. My html file looks like this.

```
<div class="load-more-<%= micropost.id %>" >
    <ol class="answers" >
      <%= render answers  %>
    </ol>
    <%= link_to "more",more_micropost_path(micropost),remote: true %>
</div> `
```

I want to load _all_answers.html.erb when more link is clicked using Ajax. my js file is

```
$(".load-more-<%= escape_javascript(micropost.id) %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('answers/all_answers')) %>");
```

and controller action is

```
def more
 micropost=Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])
 @answers=micropost.answers
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to micropost}
  format.js
end
```

end

But when I press more nothing happens. In the console I get this error

> NameError in MicropostsController#more undefined local variable or
>   method `micropost' for #<#:0x007f08be826c48>

micropost is defined in the controller but not its showing undefined. Why is it happening?

Comment: Try changing `micropost=Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])` to `@micropost=Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])` and `$(".load-more-<%= escape_javascript(micropost.id) %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('answers/all_answers')) %>");`  to `$(".load-more-<%= escape_javascript(@micropost.id) %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('answers/all_answers')) %>");`

Comment: changed micropost to @micropost. now new error undefined method `gsub' for 300:Fixnum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `$(".load-more-<%= escape_javascript(micropost.id) %>")` to `$(".load-more-<%= @micropost.id %>")` and initializing in the controller as

`@micropost = Micropost.find_by(..)`

I'm assuming it's an instance variable issue.

Comment: changed micropost to @micropost. now new error 
undefined method `gsub' for 300:Fixnum

Comment: Could you provide some more information about where this is occurring?

Comment: NoMethodError in MicropostsController#more. In my firebug on top right, there is a jquery line number which points to      xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. escape_javascript on id(should be on strings) and not using instance variable(to make them available in view) was the problem.